# Xamarin.Forms ToolBarItems issue with image and text

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have created a cross platform application in xamarin forms.In this I am using the Content Page.In the Content Page Navigation Bar i have added button using ToolBarItems.It is showing fine for Android and iOS but for UWP it is coming with the ellipsis.And when I click on ellipsis then only the button text are visible.Before clicking it seems like there is no button in the Navigation Bar.
Here Is the Screenshot of the Navigation bar before clicking the ellipsis.
[image]

Here is the screenshot of the navigation bar after the ellipsis is clicked.
[image]

Is there any way to Open the ellipsis automatically without clicking on it for UWP.
Please help.

Comment: Did you set the `Priority` on the toolbar items?

Comment: No i did not set the priority.

Comment: I deleted my prevoius answer. So basically that is a normal behaviour that you are getting for example open Weather app on Windows 10, you will see the same behaviour with Toolbar items.

Comment: Is there any way to open the ellipsis automatically when the page is loaded.I am able to hide the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

Add **Order="Primary"** in ToolbarItem

See UWB Section in [Xamarin Forms Toolbar](https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-toolbar/) for more details

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems> <ToolbarItem Order="Primary" Text="Sync" Icon="ic_sch_sync.png" Clicked="sync_clicked" x:Name="SyncItem" > </ToolbarItem> </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

There is one more requirement 
I also had the same problem 
But what I found is that if the page Title is not set then the nav bar is not shown. 
So please set title in content page constructor.

Comment: <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem  Text="Sync" Icon="ic_sch_sync.png" Clicked="sync_clicked" x:Name="SyncItem" >
        </ToolbarItem>

    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>                    this is the xaml code i used to add the button in the Navigation Page ToolBar

Comment: Hi @Harsh Chaurasia, your post is not an answer it is a comment, so please make sure that comments like this needs to go in comment section not as an answer.

Comment: I do not have the permission to write comments yet.

Comment: Updated the answer please check.

Comment: Thanx @HarshChaurasia for your reply.But the problem is still not solved after adding Order="Primary" and i am setting the Title in the Content Page Constructor.

Answer (score 0):

By default the [`CommandBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) in UWP has this natural behavior so you need to override the `IsOpen` Property of the `CommandBar` to show the text by default.

So you can create a Custom Renderer for and set its `IsOpen` property to true.

**Method 1 :**

Ok from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers) I found that both the `NavigationPage` and `ContentPage` are Custom Framework elements on UWP. So you can either debug to see how to Custom Framework incorporates the `CommandBar` and set its `IsOpen` property.

**Method 2 :**

Alternatively if you're looking for something simple you can just change the  default behavior of all the `CommandBar` styles in your UWP app by adding [this](https://file.io/jGGHns) style resource in your App.xaml in UWP. I've made the changes to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx) style with the `IsOpen` property set to true.

Comment: Thanx @AbsoluteSith for replying.Can you give me sample of how should i create a custom renderer for UWP.